# Как получить значение массива с myclass::__set_state(array())

Tags: php

Если к главному php-файлу подключен другой php-файл например через `require myfile.php` с массивом в виде:

```
<?php myclass::__set_state(array(
   'mykey' => 'myvalue'
))
```

То можно ли получить в главном файле с такого массива нужное значение по ключу и если да то как?

Пробовал

```
echo myclass::array['mykey'];
echo myclass::__set_state['mykey'];
echo myclass::__set_state(array['mykey']);
```

но ничего из этого не работает

Comment: в данном контексте myclass должно быть статическим свойством некоего класса. Это так?

Comment: Скорее `mykey` должно быть статическим свойством, а `myclass` это собственно и есть класс. Хотя не совсем понимаю вопрос, мне просто нужно иметь возможность получить `myvalue` по ключу `mykey` в любом файле, к которому подключен myfile.php

Comment: @stckvrw судя по методу `__set_state` выполняется запись в свойство класса, а не возврат значения из класса. Вам нужно как минимум написать метод для получения значения свойства из класса _myclass_, и потом вызывать этот метод.

Comment: @stckvrw  посмотрите на пример из мануала: [__set_state](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.magic.php#object.set-state)

Comment: @stckvrw В myfile.php лежит просто_массив?